# How I can create a DomainKey-Signature and DKIM-Signature by C++(or VC++) help of OpenSSL, Is it possible?

Tags: c++, email, visual-c++, openssl, email-validation

I have a public/private key pair, I submitted my public key into the server DNS TXT record(in SPF record), and I have a private key file.. I want to create DKIM-Signature and DomainKey-Signature for email, so I want to encrypt text message by private key to send it to email servers.. I want to use SHA-256 as the cryptographic hash and RSA as the public key encryption scheme.. I want to use OpenSSL and C++ to make DKIM-Signature and DomainKey-Signature for email..

This is my Public key in server TXT record :

```
 -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCnHVS+q65lvG2xocltTYgPGt9F
    aysGZTrcOwHedo8tX1dyPrcx2I8x/cvB9nmfdAkt65aGFAlBZrofbPCr2Mq4wDdv
    IZ31KSuyMQI4T68ylWNT89GewQF6AOkpY1E2bW+oDXc+MpbtpYXY1rUJAS/Abt5v
    Xi7gwKN9FSJ3mm9bjQIDAQAB
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This is my Privet key :

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIICXQIBAAKBgQCnHVS+q65lvG2xocltTYgPGt9FaysGZTrcOwHedo8tX1dyPrcx
    2I8x/cvB9nmfdAkt65aGFAlBZrofbPCr2Mq4wDdvIZ31KSuyMQI4T68ylWNT89Ge
    wQF6AOkpY1E2bW+oDXc+MpbtpYXY1rUJAS/Abt5vXi7gwKN9FSJ3mm9bjQIDAQAB
    AoGACXuxnmxRpjZOJ0FeE9TNfsXwm5jcRS2jbHHwxjYGI/YAGVyTusFmRtj3Iheh
    iTnld3SiAxPJ/qscrsHY2nef8Up60V7RF8bs+sbICnHbdz8ZoKxN9dEFCwJkIl55
    dv0GHjox6UgWUUkUAiHCM2EgG5eOOQ8PsuXY8LpPWLvfuyUCQQDbkFG9y/Q/3lmb
    CdYfBpsP3qvma+fdgCw9lRXTowhu0rKen/CC3rFkHMeHfSW9GHuR8QbPYdVA6d9H
    Y7KxYa7LAkEAwtjTEo/zAVexH/+YgiqL6w89BHlTAmwIEkXpqtAnE86kDDCekYdE
    fRIdGK1zHDOUddMAhwoJQjJzy/NJreQ8BwJBAMoJ6U3vKZjD8Ex8Jq5yE6nsyt3D
    mZ73XL5mO6l9sjrYY0kX/+dNKIro+KoyfNGef8bxtcSLUALlsnIsybf0HTUCQQCR
    DD4cvGJHJpOp4WkTxT6Bjsd6lCKyU9+yUq8/RFNC0HqYxHzWkx7uCFT2sPBXFyK2
    j4v9+v+ncs13DzZTJ+tzAkBI6UWHtsn839nrAT32M8PEPF/TuDmqebMhFOaTl4an
    W0Jr8w8iGk2gvQS2cXEPNh4XT9AgcTKDQkhui4RgxK4F
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I tried some code help of OpenSSL, but I am unable to create DKIM-Signature and DomainKey-Signature for email..

This is code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs7.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs12.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>

/ * Arguments: to be signed email, PKCS#12 certificate with private key
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc < 3) exit(1);
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    BIO *data = BIO_new_file(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!data) exit(1);

    BIO *p12file = BIO_new_file(argv[2], "rb");
    if (!p12file) exit(1);
    PKCS12 *p12 = d2i_PKCS12_bio(p12file, NULL);
    if (!p12) exit(1);

    X509 *signcert;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    STACK_OF(X509) *ca;
    int ret = PKCS12_parse(p12, "", &pkey, &signcert, &ca);
    if (!ret) exit(1);

    PKCS7 *p7 = PKCS7_sign(signcert, pkey, ca, data, 0);
    if (!p7) exit(1);

    BIO *out = BIO_new_file("email.eml", "wb");
    if (!out) exit(1);

    ret = SMIME_write_PKCS7(out, p7, data, 0);
    if (!ret) exit(1);

    BIO_free(data);
    BIO_free(p12file);
    PKCS12_free(p12);
    PKCS7_free(p7);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Any one can help me how I will use my Privet key with text to create this "DKIM-Signature and DomainKey-Signature"????

```
This is not working : BIO *p12file = BIO_new_file(argv[2], "rb");
```

I dont have "PKCS#12 certificate", so how I will use only my Privet key with email's text message to create "DKIM-Signature and DomainKey-Signature" ????

Answer (score 0):

Your private and public key are in PEM format. You can use OpenSSL to convert it to PKCS#12.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Having said this, this will not help you. The source code that you presented is for signing e-mails using S/MIME. This uses personal certificates that are signed by an official Certification Authority, not using self-signed certificates. This also provides for the ability to encrypt e-mails, provided the recipient has your public key in their key chain.

What you are looking for is DKIM and DomainKeys. This is signed and then hashed using SHA256 and SHA1, respectively. It is computationally less expensive than S/MIME, but requires canonicalization (Google it) of the header and body before hashes can be calculated.

I recommend you have a look at PHPMailer projet on Github. Although this is PHP source code, it should be readily adaptable to work in C. It only covers the DKIM implementation, but DKIM supersedes DomainKeys, so I wouldn't bother implementing DomainKeys.